# How do I render an array of items inside column using MUI-Data-Tables?

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I have list of texts that are to be displayed inside a data-table using the MUI-Data-Table component but i am facing this problem of displaying not a single item in the column but a list of items. I have an item called system. It contains an array of countries so I want to display that array inside only one column but i don't know how to do it.

this is my json :

```
systeme:{
          archived: 0
           id: 1
           nomSysteme: "Environnement Tn"
           systeme_country: Array(1)
                   {
                    0: {id: 1}
                   length: 1
                     }
        }
```

and this is how i customize my column because there is a certain pattern that i need to follow :

```
 {
    name: "titre",
    label: "Titre",
    options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
    }
},
{

    name: "theme.systeme.systeme_country",
    label: "Countries",
    options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,

    }
},
```

For more explanation the option name must be the same as in the json and it renders only one object but the theme.systeme.system_country is an array of countries's ids that i want to display but it won't let me i didn't know how to customize my columns to do such a thing or if there is a trick that i can do to make it happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide a `customBodyRender` for the specified field. An example could be found here: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/component/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

function App() {
  const data = [{ user: "john", langs: ["en", "de", "fr"] }];
  const columns = [
    { name: "user" },
    {
      name: "langs",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => (
          <div>{value.join(",")}</div>
        )
      }
    }
  ];
  return <MUIDataTable data={data} columns={columns} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: can i put the filters not inside the data-table but outside , it's like changing it's render place

Comment: How can I display only the first element of an object in an array i.e children[0].childName

Comment: You mean the first element of the list you want to render?

Comment: Is it okay if i put customBodyRender: () => {} with an empty parameter?

Comment: If you dont require one of `value, tableMeta, updateValue` it should work

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can return just the string you want
(not needed to be inside a div)

```
  const colData = (colArrayData: any) => {
        return colArrayData.map((item: any) => item.name).join(", ")
  }


  const columns = [
    { name: "user" },
    {
      name: "langs",
      options: { customBodyRender: (colArrayData: any) => colData(colArrayData) },
    }
  ];
```