# Mui-DataTables customBodyRenderLite, render multiple links in one cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I've also created an [issue](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1891) in their github for further help

I am creating an app with a lot of relationships and with [mui-datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) want to create links to different profiles within the cells. Sometimes a single cell may need to contain more than one link otherwise I would use the onCellClick function.

An example of this use case might be Pet owners and their pets (this isn't actually my use-case, just an example).

Say I create a table of Owners and then in one cell is a list of the pet names

| Owners | Pet Names |
| --- | --- |
| Paige | Sally, Sage, Ember |

I've gotten it to where I can push all the names of the animals related to a specific owner to a new array and then join that array to create a string that shows up properly with all the pets listed. When I click on the row I get taken to the owner profile with the onRowClick function which is exactly how I want it

Code Example

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [petColumns, setPetColumns] = useState([]);
    const [columnData, setColumnData] = useState([]);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState({
      filter: true,
      filterType: 'dropdown',
      responsive: 'standard',
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      resizableColumns: true,
      enableNestedDataAccess: '.',
      selectableRows: 'none',
      onRowClick: (rowData) => {
        handleClick(rowData);
      }
    })

setPetColumns = [
        {
              name: "id",
              label: "Id",
              options: {
                display: 'excluded',
               }
         },
         {
              name: "name",
              label: "Owner Name",
         },
         {
              name: "pet",
              label: "Pets",
         },
]

useEffect(() => {
    API.getOwnerData(ownerId)
        .then(res => setData(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [ownerId])

useEffect(() => {
    const ownerData = data.map((owner) => {
            const petList = []
            owner.Pets.forEach((pet) => {
              petList.push({
                name: pet.name,
              })
            })

            const petObject = {
              id: owner.id,
              name: `${owner.User.firstName} ${owner.User.lastName}`,
              pet: petList.map(p => p.name).join(', '),
            }
            return petObject
          })
   setColumnData(ownerData)
}, [data])

    const handleClick = (rowData) => {
      navigate(`${rowData[0]}`)
    }

<MUIDataTable 
    className={styles.innerTable}
    data={columnData} 
    columns={petColumns} 
    options={options}
    >
</MUIDataTable>
```

Where I'm running into trouble is that I want to turn each of the pet names that are being listed into a link that will navigate to the pets respective profile when clicked on. I will show some of my attempts to do this and explain what the results were.

ATTEMPT 1

Here I added pet.id to the petList object. This id is used with react-router-dom and Link to travel to the proper profile page for the pet. I then set up a customBodyRender (I tried both customBodyRender and customBodyRenderLite) which is supposed to map through the pet list and create a link with the pet name for each entry and then join together the new link divs.

I'm actually fairly stumped on this because I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function". Which makes me think that the value of property is not being recognized as an array. However, I found several StackOverFlow posts where value is treated properly as an array and can be joined together such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581404/how-do-i-render-an-array-of-items-inside-column-using-mui-data-tables).

I also recognize though that the array in that stack overflow is flat which mine is not but I even added the "enableNestedDataAccess: '.'," to that specific set of options (even though it's already in the general options for the table) just to make sure. I tried some variations of metadata as well but couldn't get that to stick either, I honestly think I'm probably incorporating it wrong.

CODE EXAMPLE -  **I didn't include the code that remained unchanged**

```
setPetColumns = [
        {
              name: "id",
              label: "Id",
              options: {
                display: 'excluded',
               }
         },
         {
              name: "name",
              label: "Owner Name",
         },
         {
              name: "pet",
              label: "Pets",
              options: {
                customBodyRenderLite: (value) => {    ****ATTEMPTED customBodyRender TO RENDER THE LINK AND THEN JOIN ****
                  return (
                     <>
                        {value.map((e) => {
                           <Link to={`/pets/id=${e.id}`} >{e.name}</Link>
                         }).join(', ')}
                      </>
                   )
                }
              }
         },
]

useEffect(() => {
    const ownerData = data.map((owner) => {
            const petList = []
            owner.Pets.forEach((pet) => {
              petList.push({
                name: pet.name,
                id: pet.id       ****ID IS ADDED FOR NAVIGATION PURPOSES****
              })
            })

            const petObject = {
              id: owner.id,
              name: `${owner.User.firstName} ${owner.User.lastName}`,
              pet: petList
            }
            return petObject
          })
   setColumnData(ownerData)
}, [data])
```

When I console log columnData I get exactly what I'm expecting

```
    0:
         id: "30c9"
         name: "Paige"
         property: Array(3)
                0:
                      id: "df43"
                      name: "Sally"
               1:
                      id: "dea4"
                      name: "Sage"
               2:
                      id: "ger7"
                      name: "Ember"
```

ATTEMPT 2

My attempt here was kind of a hail mary, I'd been working trying to get the custom render to work for a long while so I thought I'd go at it from a different direction. I trying to include Link within the petObject that initially worked in providing the plain joined names.

My result of this attempt was that my data table rendered but I got [ object Object ] within the pet Columns if I included return in the .map function or an empty string if there was no return. I honestly didn't really expect this to work but was at a loss of what else to try. When I consoled the columnData it was either [ object Object ] or ""

```
setPetColumns = [
        {
              name: "id",
              label: "Id",
              options: {
                display: 'excluded',
               }
         },
         {
              name: "name",
              label: "Owner Name",
         },
         {
              name: "pet",
              label: "Pets",
         },
]

useEffect(() => {
    const ownerData = data.map((owner) => {
            const petList = []
            owner.Pets.forEach((pet) => {
              petList.push({
                name: pet.name,
                id: pet.id                         ****ID IS ADDED FOR NAVIGATION PURPOSES****
              })
            })

            const petObject = {
              id: owner.id,
              name: `${owner.User.firstName} ${owner.User.lastName}`,
              *****TRIED TO INCLUDE LINK WITHIN OBJECT****
              pet: petList.map((p) => {
                   return <Link to=`/pet/id=${p.id} >p.name </Link> ****If return isn't included a blank string is returned****
                 }).join(', '), 
            }
            return petObject
          })
   setColumnData(ownerData)
}, [data])
```

| Tech | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Material-UI | 4.12.3 |
| MUI-datatables | 4.1.2 |
| React | 17.0.2 |
| browser | Google Chrome |

Comment: In the  attempt 1, why you joining the array?

Comment: Because rather than each indices being listed independently (ie. Sally Sage Ember) I wanted to make sure the comma in between was included so that it would come out as "Sally, Sage, Ember".

In my project I'm going to be dealing with hyperlinked variables that include more than one word (Ie. A full name like 'Alicia Keys') so the comma is for separation. Totally open to there being a better way to do that if there is one. If I put the comma after the link then a comma will be present even when at the end of the array which is why I use join because it only places the comma in between

Comment: Could you please share codesandbox with minimum working version?